# Positive lookbehind match all whitespaces

Tags: javascript, regex

Given these two strings:

```
browser: {
browser:  {
```

How can I write a positive lookbehind to return boolean true using .test in javascript? The pattern i have tried so far is

```
(?<=:[\s]+){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want a 'lookbehind', which does not exist. You just need to structure your regular expression better.

What's the full expression you're trying to match?

For example, if you want all :{ which have 1+ spaces between them:

    `var regex = /:\s+{/;
    regex.test('Browser: {'); //true
    regex.test('Browser:    {'); //true
    regex.test('Browser:{'); //false`

There's no need for a capture group if you only want a boolean.

Answer (score 4):

**No Lookbehind in JavaScript, but alternatives exist...**

- JavaScript regex does not support lookbehind
- If you must have lookbehind, the alternate [XRegGexp](http://xregexp.com/) regex library has it, as well as other useful features
- One classic workaround for engines that don't support lookbehind is to match a string `(in)(pieces)(in capture groups)` and only to retrieve the groups that interest you.

This example shows you how to retrieve what you want from a capture group, while ignoring what you don't want.

```
var myregex = /This must be here, but don't want to match it(I want this)/i;
var matchArray = myregex.exec(yourString);
if (matchArray != null) {
    thematch = matchArray[1];
} else {
    thematch = "";
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning `XRegExp`, that is really powerful.

Answer (score 1):

The below regex would capture whitespace after :

```
:([^{]*)
```

Javascript won't support lookbehind, so i used capture group to capture the spaces which are present just after to `:`.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/45)